# Finish the activity intent in asynytask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, activity-finish

hi im currently working on android mysql for my libary mobile application but  How can i close the log in activity after i log in , context .finish(); is not working here's my codes.i know in normal intent its only finish();
but how can i do it in my code.

my asyntask:

```
public class backgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    String result;

    backgroundWorker(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.254.120/LibrayAPI/Signin.php";

        if (type.equals("login")) {


            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];


            try {

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter((conn.getOutputStream()));

                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                //Read server response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                return sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new String("Exeption" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Log in Status");
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("\tLoading");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();

        if (result.equals("Log in sucessful")) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            Intent todash = new Intent(context, DashBoard.class);
            context.startActivity(todash);

        } else {
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Log in Activity:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        password = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {

        String Username = username.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        //notif call
//call notif for overdue tommorow
        backWorkerNotifTom backWorkerNotifTom = new backWorkerNotifTom(this);
        //get datetime tom
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        Date dateTom = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateTomString = sf1.format(dateTom);
        Toast.makeText(this, dateTomString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backWorkerNotifTom.execute("SelectNotifTom",dateTomString,Username);

        backWorkerNotif backWorkerNotif = new backWorkerNotif(this);
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat SF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String DateNow = SF.format(date);
        backWorkerNotif.execute("Notif", DateNow, Username);

        String Type = "login";
        GlobalVariable.BorrowerID = Username;
        GlobalVariable.Password = Password;
        backgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new backgroundWorker(this);
        _backgroundWorker.execute(Type, Username, Password);


    }
}
```

PS: looks like im new to android.

Comment: Your "Button" block: is that in your Activity?

Comment: editedmy code above

Comment: thats log in activity is the activity i want to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use Activity instead of Context

```
Activity context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

String result;

backgroundWorker(Activity ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
```

Give `Login.this` isntead of context when you call backgroundWorker

```
backgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new backgroundWorker(Login.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to finish your Activity from the AsyncTask would be to change your Context type:

```
public class backgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Login context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    String result;

    backgroundWorker(Login ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    //...
}
```

Then, in your `onPostExecute()` you can just call:

```
context.finish();
```

You're passing `this` to the constructor from your Login Activity, so you won't need to change how you construct the Task. This means that your AsyncTask can only be constructed from that Activity, but that's probably all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to finish the Activity from your AsyncTask you need to pass an Activity reference in the AsyncTask constructor.

```
public class backgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    private Activity mActivity;
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    String result;

    backgroundWorker(Activity activity) {
        context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    ......

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do your job
        mActivity.finish();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for two Context references.

Answer (score 1):

Just add only one line to finish Log in acitivity.....

```
 @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          alertDialog.setMessage(result);
          alertDialog.show();
          if (result.equals("Log in sucessful")) {
               alertDialog.dismiss();
               ((Activity)context).finish();//just add this line of code
               Intent todash = new Intent(context, DashBoard.class);
               context.startActivity(todash);

          } else {
              //do your work
          }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a WeakReference in your AsyncTask, this will avoid possible context leaks. You can achieve this like this:

```
public class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<Activity> mWeakContext;

    public MyAsynctask(WeakReference<Activity> reference) {
        mWeakContext = reference;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do your work
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Activity activity = mWeakContext.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of handling is create a interface and notify the caller once async is done its task.

```
  public interface asyncTaskStatusListener {
        void onfinishTask();
    }
```

//make your login activity to implement interface

```
  public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements asyncTaskStatusListener {

    @Override
     public void onfinishTask() {
      finish();
   }
 }

   //Create your background class constructor which takes interface reference.
   backgrounderWorker = new backgroundworker(asyncTaskStatusListener callback);

    //In post execute method call 
    callback.onfinishTask();
```